# Can't get request when config routes.rb file with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

My app structure like this

```
Gemfile
app.rb
config.ru
lib/routes.rb


# app.rb
require 'sinatra'
class Todo < Sinatra::Base
  set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV']

  Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib', '*.rb')].each {|lib| load lib}
end

#config.ru
require 'sinatra'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'development'

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app.rb')

Todo.start!

#lib/routes.rb
get '/' do
  "Hello world"
end
```

When I run with `ruby config.rb` then locate to `localhost:4567`, it doesn't recognize the route `/`. But if I move the code `get '/' do` into `class Todo` it works.

Anyone can explain that for me?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `config.ru` file, that means that the application has to be invoked by the `rackup` utility and not `ruby config.ru`. The reason for this is that `rackup` sets a lot of settings before invoking the code inside `config.ru`. [Rackup utility](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1-6-stable/bin/rackup#L4) is part of Rack gem that Sinatra builds on, so it will be present if you install Sinatra.

Although not a problem for the example you provided, in a modular style application, you need to require `sinatra/base` rather than just `sinatra`.